# Case number range formula

Tags: formula, case, crmfusion

I've developed a formula that was functional for my Leads. The formula was giving which lead is cold,warm or hot.

Formula below:

```
CASE( Formula_SUM_ALL__c , 
-30, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48), 
-25, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48), 
-20, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48), 
-15, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
-10, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
-5, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
  0, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
  5, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
 10, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
 15, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
 20, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
 25, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
 30, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0", "WARM", 16,48),
 35, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0", "WARM", 16,48),
 40, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0", "WARM", 16,48),
 45, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0", "WARM", 16,48),
 50, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0", "WARM", 16,48),
 55, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0", "WARM", 16,48),
 60, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0", "WARM", 16,48),
 65, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0", "WARM", 16,48),
 70, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP", "HOT", 16,48),
 75, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP", "HOT", 16,48),
 80, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP", "HOT", 16,48),
 85, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP", "HOT", 16,48),
 90, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP", "HOT", 16,48),
 95, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP", "HOT", 16,48),
100, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP", "HOT", 16,48),
null)
```

Before:
[image]

After new edits:
[image]

With Amit suggestion:
[image]
Now what i want is to make it smaller . Can I somehow go with the range of numbers? For example use case as well but not to exceed the compiling ?

**Formula_SUM_ALL__c** = Formula_Video__c + Formula_Monetization__c + Formula_OVP__c + Formula_Social_Media_Popularity__c + Formula_Status__c

**Formula_Video__c** = IF( ISPICKVAL( Has_Video_Type__c , "No") , 0, 25)

**Formula_Monetization__c**  = IF (ISBLANK(Video_Monetizing_tool__c), 
NULL, 
IF(OR(INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,"No"), INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,"N/A")), 
0, 
10 
) 
)

**Formula_OVP__c** =  CASE( OVP_used__c , 
"Brightcove", 10, 
"Flow Player",10, 
"Haivision",10, 
"JW Player", 10, 
"Kaltura",10, 
"Piksel",10, 
"Qbrick", 10, 
"StreamUK",10, 
"thePlatform",10, 
"Vimeo",10, 
"Vyoo",10, 
"Youtube",10, 
"N/A",0, 
"None",0, 
0)

**Formula_Social_Media_Popularity__c**  = IF( Formula_SUM_Social__c > 0 && Formula_SUM_Social__c < 5000, 0, 
IF( Formula_SUM_Social__c >= 5000 && Formula_SUM_Social__c < 10000 , 5, 
IF( Formula_SUM_Social__c >= 10000, 10, null) ) )

**Formula_SUM_Social__c**  = Facebook_Fans__c + Twitter_Fans__c + Linkedin_Followers__c

**Formula_Status__c** = CASE( Status , 
"None",0, 
"Contacted/Campaign in Progress", 10, 
"Not Responding", -30, 
"Prospect in communication", 35, 
"Not Interested", -30, 
"Close to Converting",45, 
"May Convert One Day",10 
,null)

Comment: Its not hitting compile size. its good. Why do you want to change it ?

Comment: It's hitting the compiled size because that formula field that i have is made from many small formulas and if i use If statement, for every time i call that field it doubles the values in the compiling.

Comment: If you show the formula for the `Formula_SUM_ALL__c` field we may be able to help to reduce the size of that.

Comment: Can you include `Formula_SUM_Social__c` as well?

Comment: @BarCotter done.

Comment: If you apply my suggestion that has reference to "Formula_SUM_ALL__c" only twice, does it work or still hit the compile size?

Comment: It's for 427 more characters than allowed :/

Comment: Changing the `Formula_Social_Media_Popularity__c`  formula to `IF(Formula_SUM_Social__c < 5000, 0, IF(Formula_SUM_Social__c < 10000 , 5, 10))` will get you closer to the limit. The only difference is that it will return 0 rather than null when `Formula_SUM_Social__c` is below 0.

Comment: @BarCotter thank you this actually work. If you can manage to make other fields smaller it will save me allot of work. 
Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This might help, Compile size if far less(371):

```
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c < 30,IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "COLD", 16,48),
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c < 70,IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0", "WARM", 16,48),
IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP", "HOT", 16,48)))
```

Comment: This doesn't help because the values go way up...
Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (5,427 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters

Comment: How is that formula too big to execute? It's a lot shorter than your original formula.

Comment: Because in this example, Formula_SUM_ALL__c is referenced twice, which means that its compile size is multiplied by 2. See https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf to understand the difference between compile size and formula length.

Answer (score 3):

@Amit Bangads solution, which uses [IF](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#IF) rather than [CASE](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#CASE), would greatly reduce the amount of characters being used and allows you to use number ranges.

If you wanted to use more formula fields you could add a new field for the Image URL

**Formula_WeatherImage__c:**

```
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 25, "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg",
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 65,"/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0",
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 100,"/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP",
null)))
```

And something similar for the text

**Formula_WeatherText__c:**

```
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 25, "COLD",
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 65,"WARM",
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 100,"HOT",
null)))
```

Your formula for the image then becomes:

```
IMAGE(Formula_WeatherImage__c, Formula_WeatherText__c, 16,48)
```

**BUT** bare in mind that SalesForce will compile the formula back into one larger formula. e.g. in the formula above it will substitute the `Formula_WeatherImage__c` field name for all the formula text from within that field. Which would end up being compiled on the backend to something like:

```
IMAGE(IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 25, "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg",
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 65,"/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3F0",
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 100,"/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002Y3FP",
null))), IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 25, "COLD",
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 65,"WARM",
IF(Formula_SUM_ALL__c <= 100,"HOT",
null))), 16,48)
```

Comment: its true that Amit formula reduce the characters in that specific case but not on global compile level when I have  10 other small formulas that I call every time I use Formula_SUM_ALL__c. 
With each calling of the Formula_SUM_ALL__c  i get around 2600 characters multiply by 3 its more than 7500 characters specified in that if statement.

Comment: It sounds like you may have to fine tune your other formula fields as well

Comment: I've made edits in the question you can see the problem specified @BarCotter

Answer (score 0):

Which edition of Salesforce do you have? If you have Enterprise Edition, you can use a workflow field update to set a regular Number field value to be equal to the same formula you are using for Formula_SUM_ALL__c. This would allow you to use Amit's example and not worry about the compile size, because it would use the compile size of the number field (marginal), rather than the compile size of the formula (large).

The steps are (from the [Tips for Reducing Formula Size](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf) tip sheet):

1. Create a custom field of the type your field update formula will return, such as Date or Number. Don’t add it to any page layouts.
2. Create a workflow rule on the object. Set it to execute whenever a record is created or updated.
3. Create a Field Update workflow action. Choose the custom field you created in Step 1 as the target, and the large formula into the formula that sets the value in that field.
4. In your formula field, reference your custom field instead of the formula.

All of your smaller formulas look pretty optimized at this point, so I don't think there's a lot you can do to reduce the size of Formula_SUM_ALL__c.