# Dashboard to show hot leads daily

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I've developed a formula that defines the quality of the leads for my company. You can find more in the  following article: [Case number range formula](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/case-number-range-formula?noredirect=1#comment76303_58036)

Now that I know who are my hot leads i want to make a report that will give only the hot leads of the day.
So for example today i have 14 hot leads, tomorrow I might have 22. Some of the leads from the previous day might stay in the next day.
I want this dashboard to shown graph explained below.

**X-axis** to show days.

**Y-axis** to show Hot leads.

Please advise,

Darko

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Make report that get information for the following.

***Reports***

1. **Summarize information by**: Lead Status
2. **Show**: All Leads
3. *Followed by the Time frame below*
4. Range should be **custom**.
5. From and to you can select any value that you want.
6. Group the report by **Last Modified** or by **Date Created** (which suits you better)
7. **Save** the report.

***Dashboards***

1. Go to **Dashboards**.
2. Select **Components**
3. Select **Line Chart**
4. Insert the report that you saved previously into the line chart.
5. Go to **Settings** inside the line chart.
6. Select **Component Data**

   - **X-axis** to show Date Modified or Date Created
   - **Y-axis** to show Lead
   - Group by **Lead Status**
   - **Status Display** units to show Whole Units .

Done.